# Android Soft Keyboard freezes visible layout until closed

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a bunch of `EditText`'s inside a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. When I click on one of them, soft keyboard appears normally, and my `EditText` appears focused. But when I type, **the text doesn't show up. Not even cursor is showing. When I tap another `EditText`, or a Button that should make a visible change (add views), or click Next on the keyboard, nothing visually changes**. But once I close the keyboard (with Back button or programmatically), I can finally see changes: typed text appears and desired `EditText` is selected.

As if everything works correctly, only the screen is frozen until I close soft input, and then I can see progress.

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?**
Closing the keyboard programmatically can't pass because I need Next button on the keyboard to work, and constant opening/closing makes my UI look confusing.

**My `EditText`'s are all like this and are different from each other only by ID and Hint.**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dataFullName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Personal name"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textPersonName|textVisiblePassword"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

**This is `ScrollView` holding the `LinearLayout` that's holding my `EditText`**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/generalsScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <!-- my EditText's here -->


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Additional information:"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/additional_text" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/generalsContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/additional_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/generalsAdder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/newGeneralButton"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bttn_bg"
                android:onClick="newGeneralButtonPressed"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorLink="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for facing this problem before me and putting a question and an answer to this problem. Let me try it your way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved my problem again. There were too many EditText's in the same LinearLayout. So I just divided them in 2 LinearLayout's and now it's good. Does anyone have the idea why that's  happening?

Comment: It didn't help. I only have two `EditText`s. Also for me, this problem arises when `EditText` are near to the bottom of phone and keyboard has to move them to top to be displayed above keyboard. It doesn't arise when `EditText` is already on the top and nothing moved on keyboard appearance. Also this only happens in Android 9, not in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was in only Android 9 Pie, and it got fixed by setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54196952/1708390) is the reference to that solution.